# LessCSS : ID in front of variable

Tags: css, variables, less

My site has a global variable for the font-size like so:

```
@default-fontsize : 12px;
```

Today I learned that my project will also be in Arabic and Chinese and the font-size in those 2 sites has to be increased by 2px. Which would result in having:

```
@default-fontsize : 14px;
```

Since I don't want to change my variable, I put an ID on the body tag and I would like to do this but it doesn't work:

```
#foreign-language { font-size: (@default-fontsize + 2); }
```

Anyone knows the solution to this?

Comment: why not #foreign-language { font-size: 14px; } ?

Comment: @watson Because you'll have to adjust the font size in two locations rather than just the default.

Comment: @user2019515 not if you use em

Comment: The variable is declared multiple times with different operations. Setting a static font-size on my ID is not what I am looking to achieve. Sometimes the font-size is 12, 16, 20, 30... So the variable helps achieve this easily.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you really don't want to target the id to just have its size changed, which is what your original code...

```
#foreign-language { font-size: (@default-fontsize + 2); }
```

...does, by producing css as:

```
#foreign-language {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

I believe what you really want is to change the `@default-fontsize` so it propogates throughout your LESS code elsewhere. Now, you cannot do this by using an id, as the LESS is already compiled into static CSS by the time the code is looking at id's on the `body` element. You need to already know whether you are going to feed the browser a foreign language prepared set of CSS or not during the compile phase.

Now, you can make the code flexible so that once you know if you are modifying it or not, you tell it to change value. You can do something like this with a mixin:

```
.setFontSize(@addSize: 0) { 
  @default-fontsize: 12px + @addSize;
}
```

Then call only one of the two following, depending on which language set you are dealing with:

```
.setFontSize(); //do this normally
.setFontSize(2); //do this to increase it for those you need to
```

Then use the variable where you need it:

```
body {
  font-size: @default-fontsize;
}
```

Again, this is not something that can be done "on the fly" with LESS based off whether the body has a `foreign-language` id on it. Instead, you need to tell the LESS to compile differently if you know you are dealing with the foreign language. You could set up a global variable like:

```
@addFontSize: 0; //change to 2 when dealing with a foreign language
```

And then just have a single call to the mixin like so:

```
.setFontSize(@addFontSize); //will change based off your global variable setting
```

Comment: I will look into this Mixin thing, thank you for the answer! :)